# Wordpress API fields modification

Tags: rest-api

I want to modify some content in WordPress API, specific I want to change Latin words to Cyrillic if there is a parameter in the API endpoint. It works for most of the fields, but for _embeded fields, I can't modify the response. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What API? How are you making the calls, how and what are you able to modify (example code) and where are you failing with this attempt (example code)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.